# How to add List of Object in Proto Datastore and Observe in view model

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to add a list of userserData object' in the proto datastore.

here is my protobuf schema

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.wkt.distriware";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message LoginResponse {
  message UserData {
    string username = 1;
    string userType = 2;
    string token = 3;
    bool isActive = 4;
  }
  repeated UserData usersData = 1;
}
```

And this is the class that is responsible for updating and getting the userData.

```
class LoginResProtoDataStore(
    context: Context
) {

    private val dataStore = context.loginResponseDataStore

    val userData: Flow<LoginResponse.UserData> = dataStore.data
        .map { loginResponse ->
            val userDataObject = LoginResponse.UserData.getDefaultInstance()
            loginResponse.usersDataList.map { user ->
                if(user.isActive) {
                    val userDataBuilder = userDataObject.toBuilder()
                    userDataBuilder.username = user.username
                    userDataBuilder.userType = user.userType
                    userDataBuilder.token = user.token
                }
            }
            userDataObject
        }

    suspend fun updateUserData(user: User) {
        dataStore.updateData { loginResponse ->
            val userData = LoginResponse.UserData.newBuilder()
            userData.username = user.username
            userData.userType = user.userType
            userData.token = user.token
            loginResponse.toBuilder()
                .addUsersData(userData).build()
        }
    }
}
```

The *LoginResponse.UserData* is generated class from protobuf schema.
What I want here to do is to update the list in the proto datastore and observe using Kotlin Flow as live data. I can tell that the userdata is saving in that proto datastore but the problem is I don't know why the observer is not triggered every time the proto datastore is updated.

Thak you in advance :)

Comment: Where is the logic you have in place for observing the flow?